# Can i create an array that has multiple objects and then manipulate that array throughout my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an array of jquery objects that I want to hide when a particular click event is triggered. Instead of looping through the contents of the same array for each click event can I transform the array into a single object or something that I can just attach a method on to?

I have a current fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hd5qa/13/

Sorry if this sounds vague, I'm not sure how to best explain this.

Kyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can create an empty jQuery object and then call [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) on it for each element.

```
var all = $();
$.each(myArray, function(index, element) { all = all.add(element); });
// now you can use all to apply something to all of them
all.show();
all.hide();
// etc
```

**See your updated demo [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBba4/).**

Comment: Additionally, if you use [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), it becomes even nicer: `var all = _.reduce(myArray, function(all, elem) { return all.add(elem); }, $());` **See it [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9LnE/).**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a couple ways to do it. You can select them all at once:

```
var colors = $('#blue, #red, #green, #black, ...');
```

You can combine the individual collections into a single collection

```
var $blue = $('#blue');
var $red = $('#red');
var $green = $('#green');
var $black = $('#black');
var $purple = $('#purple');
var $orange = $('#orange');

var collection = $blue.add($red).add($green).add(.....
```

Or you can just give all the elements a `class="color"` attribute

```
var collection = $('.color');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compose a jQuery object with the
[`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
method. Then call methods of your composed object like normal.

e.g.

```
var ALL=$('#blue').add('#red');
ALL.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not give them all a class?

```
myArray.each(function() { $(this).addClass("myArrayClass"); });
```

Then you can just

```
$(".myArrayClass").hide();
```

You could also use classes to assign the same onclick event handler to all of the click buttons at once.